# Making a 2d sprite based game in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, platformer

I'm looking at developing a 2D sprite based platformer. Usually I make games in Gamemaker, because I find it very easy to use. I have never used Unity before but have heard a lot of good things. So, just wondering whether you can easily make this type of game in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Yes you can.  You can do this in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a sprite based game in Unity, and it can be considered easy, but it is not the same kind of easy as Gamemaker's.

Even learning Unity can be daunting if you don't have somebody knowledgeable to help you out or at least experience with different ways of programming.

Once you know it, getting a basic game running in Unity will take a lot more work than it would in Gamemaker. Gamemaker is designed to make these kinds of games - they have more of your game already baked into the project from the start. Unity is much more general, basically meaning you need to specify more to get a game. There are also some artifacts of Unity being a 3d engine - a 2d game is actually a 3d game that is only shown from one angle in Unity.

However, Unity is very good at keeping large projects organised, and C# is more suitable for big projects. In both Unity and Gamemaker I experience a slowdown in my development speed as my project gets bigger, but with Gamemaker the curve is sharper and sooner. And finally, knowledge gained in Unity is more applicable elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Unity has added lot of features to support 2D games.

- Automatic Sprite Slicing
- Automatic Sprite Animation
- Alpha Cutout
- Sprite Packer 2D physics

Here is a link to start with Unity 2D :)

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation